# Particles do not render

Tags: rendering, particles, eevee-render-engine

I'm emitting grass (2 meshes into a Collection) on a mesh. **Everything works fine in the EEVEE realtime preview but those particles are not visible/rendered in the final EEVEE render.**

I'm using Blender 2.91.2

2 pictures : First one is the Preview, second one is the render.
[image: Eevee PREVIEW]
[image: Eevee RENDER]

Blend file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vcl6Lz52V2MnKmsSOT3L_kBaE1icoxaG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you also add screenshots of it

Comment: hello please share your file (at least the part that is emitting particles with its particle object): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello @moonboots, Link to Blend file added.

Comment: you need to reactivate the visibility of your grass object in the Outliner, I don't know if there's a way to hide the original objects though

Comment: I don't think the problem is the visibility of of my objects, in the following test scene, everything works fine with visibility deactivated : https://drive.google.com/file/d/14DdgTWquVcIuF87bxLyRouk2XxVGpABm/view?usp=sharing.  Am I wrong ?

Comment: yes but if you put it into a collection, and deactivate the cube visibility in this collection, the cube won't be visible either

Comment: I'm not sure it's the way it's supposed to work though, it may need a report

Comment: Thanks for your help.